# MySQL Workbench. Как вставить в поле с типом Varchar() строку с русскими символами?

Tags: mysql, кодировка, mysql-workbench, charset

Доброго времени суток!

Пытаюсь выполнить следующий скрипт SQL:

```
INSERT INTO classification (`Type`, `Subtype`) VALUES ("тип", "подтип");
```

Выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xD1\x82\xD0\xB8\xD0\xBF' for column 'Type' at row 1
```

Перепробовал различные кодировки для таблицы: cp1251, utf-8, utf8mb4, cp1251_bin.

Долго не могу найти решение проблемы. Может быть, кто сталкивался с данной проблемой и подскажет. Благодарю!

**UPD.** Результат выполнения строки `show variables like '%char%'`:

[image: show variables like char]

Comment: введи запрос `show variables like '%char%';` и покажи таблицу, которую  он выведет.....соединение в какой кодировке происходит?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я обновил вопрос, взгляните.

Comment: так как вы подцепили к проекту существующую ранее и созданную ранее базу , возможно ранее были  - либо другая локаль системы , либо другая кодировка,  в которой база сохраняла записанное значение, могу конечно ошибаться , так как немного сталкивался со скулем , но там можно задать кодировку для сохранения данных ... и если она отличалась от общей кодировки - при конверте данных из одного приложения в другое вы получите и разные ( нечитаемые ) в одном из полеи перекодированные символы , о чем вам и говорит приложение  '\xD1\x82\xD0\xB8\xD0\xBF'

Comment: @Eikhner и что с этим можно сделать? наверняка есть команды для установки кодировок базы данных, сервера и т.д.

Comment: а это уже нужно смотреть, скорее всего,  при добавлении базы данных с сущностями в ваш проект , возможно,  там можно как то указать кодировки для разных полеи, другого пути , если проблема в этом , я не знаю , извините ...

Comment: друга , попробуи вот это https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/ , экспорт базы или таблицы из базы в аксесс , или во что то другое , и потом уже из этого чего то другого , забираи себе данные в студию ...если не получится  - дам скаип  - тебе все переконвертят ...

Comment: @Eikgner я уже нашел интересное решение на англоязычном stackoverflow: там вместо типа `varchar` предлагают использовать `nvarchar`, который, как я понял, поддерживает unicode. И все заработало (mysql при указании типа `nvarchar` превращал его в `varchar` и `set charset latin1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение мне дали на англоязычном stack overflow:

Вместо типа varchar предлагают использовать `nvarchar` в MySQL Workbench, который, как они утверждают, поддерживает unicode. И все заработало (mysql при указании типа `nvarchar` превращал его в `varchar` и `set charset latin1`).

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же проблема. Выполняю команду INSERT INTO если указывать в значениях для таблицы VALUES русские символы выдает ошибку, тип данных столбца VARCHAR и CHAR. Сегодня попробую указать тип данных NVARCHAR. Ещё нашел решение, пока не пробовал, в  VALUES перед значением указывать букву N , пример VALUES (N'тип', N' подтип') ;

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Изменение кодировки таблицы сработало
[image: Смена кодировки]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]